# Using Double datatype for if Statement

Tags: c#

```
 double similarity = matcher.Match(features1, features2);
    if (similarity== ?? ) // What sould i write here 
    {
       Application.Exit();
  }
```

if feature1 and feature2 matches than application should exit please help me

Comment: What does the `Match` method return? What is the logic for the value it returns? .. this means nothing to us.

Comment: Whatever you write in if statement; compiler doesn't care. but end of the day they should evaluate to a `Boolean` else compiler won't be happy.

Comment: it returns double datatype value

Comment: ..and what sort of numeric value does it return for a given similarity? We don't know the logic so we can't help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Double` is a *floating point type* we usually compare `Double` using ***tolerance***, e.g.

```
Double tolerance = 0.001;

// Instead of just features1 == features2
if (Math.Abs(features1 - features2) <= tolerance) {
  Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: ... but we still have no idea what OP's `Match` logic is.

Answer (score -1):

You need a boolean not a double.

```
bool similarity = matcher.Match(features1, features2);
if (similarity) 
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Make sure your mather.Match method returns a bool.

If you really need matcher.Match to return a double then please share your code with us so we can understand why you need this and then help you.

Comment: The OP has outlined that the method returns `double`. Also, note that the OP is attempting to create a boolean expression via the `==` equality operator.

Comment: it returns double not bool..  what should i do then ?? :(

Comment: I was still typing my answer when he replied he was certain that he needed a double. I also edited my answer after the update.

Comment: @Legend can we see your matcher.Match method?